# Rails JSON store value gets quoted upon saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, postgresql

I have this problem with my Rails (5.1.6) application that is running on a PostgreSQL instance.

I have a model with a JSON type column (`t.json :meta`). The model has a store accessor like

`store :meta, accessors: [:title], coder: JSON`

The problem is now when I set this value that it shows up in the database as

`"{\"title\":\"I am a title\"}"`

making it text rather than a JSON value, which in turn makes that I cannot use the JSON query operator (`->>`) to query my JSON fields. I already tried without the coder option, but this results in it being saved as YAML.
The serialize function also did not change anything for me (adding `serialize :meta, JSON`)

Any and all help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[serialize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html#method-i-serialize) and [store](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Store.html) are not intended to be used for native JSON columns. Their purpose is to marshal and un-marshal data into string columns.

This was a "poor mans" JSON storage before native JSON support existed (and was supported by ActiceRecord). Using it on a JSON column will result in a double encoded string as you have noticed.

You don't actually have to do anything to use a JSON column. Its handled by the adapter.

See:

- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html#method-i-serialize
- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#json-and-jsonb

Comment: Okay, thanks for setting that straight. Is there an easy way to define an accessor for the data that lives inside of the JSON? So I do not have to call `meta["title"]` everytime I want to access the title?

Comment: Answering my own question here; `store_accessor` does this.